# Word field definition issue after save

Tags: ms-word, docx4j

I have field definition in Word 2016 (Office 365 same problem) like this

```
                    <w:r>
                        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
                        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> DOCPROPERTY "UohsDate" \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
                        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
                    </w:r>
```

after filling field by docx4j, editing document in word and saving document again, my field definition is divided into two:

```
                    <w:r>
                        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> DOCPROPERTY "UohsDa</w:instrText>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">te" \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
                    </w:r>
```

Please, any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: So to clarify, Word changed it?

Comment: @JasonPlutext exactly! Word divided the field after save. This field is type Text, but contains date. Maybe that's the problem. I've changed the type to Date, but then was value required and I need it empty.

Comment: @Kazimír, one of my users has the same issue, but I was not able to duplicate using provided steps, did you find a solution?